# How to read from a case class in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, case-class

I am new to Scala. I have a case class. The code is given below.

```
case class ReportInfoPosted(
  name:  Option[String],
  id:    Option[String],
  order: Option[Int]
)
```

I also have a function which returns an **seq** of objects of the class. This is what is being returned.

```
ReportInfoPosted(Some(Sales Dollars),Some(4e6d8ec1-4c00-4193-be15-2fa0509849a7),Some(0))
```

Now I want to read values from the object. I have looked at some resources on the web, this is what I have tried.

```
for(el <- reportlist){
    println(el.input)
}

for(el <- reportlist){
    println(el.id)
}
```

BTW, **reportlist** is the **seq** of obejcts. None are working. I don't know what to do.

Comment: What compilation/runtime-error messages do you get, what happens if you just println(reportlist)? What does your program output?

Comment: You have no `input` field in `ReportInfoPosted` so the line `println(el.input)` won't work

Comment: @ccheneson, I did that by mistake.

Comment: It says Equals does not take parameters

Comment: I have also tried reportlist(0).name with success

Comment: @eddard.stark Please update your OP with the correction about `input`

Comment: If it says "equals does not take parameters" then your problem lies outside of the code you've posted in the question. Does it give a line number? Can you post more of the code?

Comment: when I write reportlist(0).name it gives me an error there

Comment: Also: http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague.  Do you just mean this?

```
val a = ReportInfoPosted(Some("a"), Some("a"), Some(1))
val b = ReportInfoPosted(Some("b"), Some("b"), Some(2))
val reportlist: Seq[ReportInfoPosted] = Seq(a,b)

for (report <- reportlist) {
  println(report.name)
}
```

prints:

```
Some(a)
Some(b)
```

Comment: are Seq and Vector the same? I don't know, I have to say I am really new at this.

Comment: A Vector is a subtype of Seq.  Any Seq class will work exactly the same is this example.

Comment: Umm my client has written Seq.. It is not compiling. Always some error regarding equals. What is equals?